# Logic to show how many times a button is chosen

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Question and buttons]I am currently using excel-vba and I am trying to create a simple question and answer. So far I have a question in my excel sheet that will answer the above question. I have four buttons that when you choose each button a message will appear. I want to find out if I can add some logic to each button to show how many times the button was chosen and also how many times this question was answered?

I have tried researching this but most of the answers show in Java and android programming. None with excel-vba.

```
Sub Tomatoes()


MsgBox "Correct"
End Sub

Sub Cucumbers()

MsgBox "Wrong Answer, that would be too healthy, Please choose again."
End Sub

Sub Lime()

MsgBox "Incorrect Answer, that ketchup would be exteremely sour."
End Sub

Sub Apples()

MsgBox "Incorrect, Apples with Ketchup would be horrible. "
End Sub
```

Each button is created so that when chosen it will display a different option. Is there a way to add logic to each button to show how many times it was chosen? and also add logic to show how many times this question was answered?

Comment: Should the counts ever get reset? If so, when?

Comment: The counts will only be reset when the worksheet is closed and the counts would show on another sheet. Like say maybe sheet2? to show how many times that option was chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Form controls, which have the advantage that you can point all of them to the same Sub.  So create a new sub like so and point all of your buttons to this.  This sub will increment the counters appropriately on your Sheet2.  Here's what Sheet2 should look like:

[image]

```
Sub btnIngredient_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsQuestion As Worksheet
    Dim wsCounts As Worksheet
    Dim rDest As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsQuestion = wb.ActiveSheet
    Set wsCounts = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Select Case wsQuestion.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters.Text
        Case "Cucumbers":   Set rDest = wsCounts.Range("B3")
                            MsgBox "Wrong Answer, that would be too healthy, Please choose again."

        Case "Tomatoes":    Set rDest = wsCounts.Range("B4")
                            MsgBox "Correct"

        Case "Lime":        Set rDest = wsCounts.Range("B5")
                            MsgBox "Incorrect Answer, that ketchup would be exteremely sour."

        Case "Apples":      Set rDest = wsCounts.Range("B6")
                            MsgBox "Incorrect, Apples with Ketchup would be horrible. "

    End Select

    wsCounts.Range("B2").Value = wsCounts.Range("B2").Value + 1 'Increase counter of the total times question answered
    rDest.Value = rDest.Value + 1   'Increase counter of individual button clicked

End Sub
```

To clear the counters on workbook close, use the Workbook_BeforeClose event (make sure this code is in the `ThisWorkbook` code module):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Me.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B6").Value = 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The Sub's for each button could track the information you need.  With the addition of some module-level variables, your code could look similar to this:

```
Private CucumbersPressed As Integer
Private TomatoesPressed As Integer
Private QuestionAnswered As Integer

Private Sub Cucumbers()
   CucumbersPressed = CucumbersPressed + 1
   QuestionAnswered = QuestionAnswered + 1

   MsgBox "Wrong"
End Sub

Private Sub Tomatoes()
   TomatoesPressed = TomatoesPressed + 1
   QuestionAnswered = QuestionAnswered + 1

   MsgBox "Correct"
End Sub
```

Depending on the number of questions and the number of buttons, this approach could become unwieldy.  In that case, some other mechanism would be needed but the idea would be similar.